How to comment an obsolete else-case?
In C#, I have the following piece of source code:
if (condition)
{
    action_1();
}
else
{
    action_2();
}
action_3();

This clearly means that:

condition is true => perform action_1.
condition is false => perform action_2.
Always perform action_3.

I have put action_2() in comment, compiled it and (using JetBrains) decompiled it, and I see the following:
if (condition)
{
  action_1();
}
else
  action_3();

This gives me the impression that the following happens:

condition is true => perform action_1.
condition is false => perform action_3.

=> This is wrong! I want action_3 to be performed Always.
For your information, I have commented action_2(), but obviously not the curly braces. This is my code:
if (condition)
{
    action_1();
}
else
{
    // action_2();
}
action_3();

Can anybody confirm (please use official references):

I am right and the decompiler is wrong.
The decompiler is right and I am wrong => NEVER put an empty { ... } after a else case.


You can easily find out whether the decompiler is right by running the code. Does action_3 get executed when condition is true?

Here is another decompiler that does it right: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6A6gJYAuAFtgPYC2LApgHa0AUARkyYAbdAGMmnYHWoSAlPkLElipUWoAzHuMnS5K1QSSrj6AIKjaMznB6yA3PqUBfR8XZCAzu1dFDJ1QD0AWYWVjC2DkYmLlHG5pYSqBH6McqxJJgUNAxMAK60zGxcvALCYhJSCZzyfiY+6BpaFbrV9bX+RPFWNvb1qSbuXm31Sl0S4b3pzvVjnEmT0+n6aJkhVT34/UQr5GthtpvLpBSz84dITkA=

"using JetBrains" Which tool did you use exactly? dotPeek?

@SomeBody: are you saying that the decompiler is indeed wrong and that action_3 is indeed always executed?

@Sweeper: I'm indeed using JetBrains dotPeek, version 2021.3.2, built on 2021-12-22. I'm checking for an update.

Can you share exactly the code which you compiled and then decompiled? We currently have to infer it from your description. If e.g. you commented out the { and } as well but didn't mention it, that would change the question...

Please include the "commented" version of the code. It sounds like you left the else but commented out action_2(); as well as the braces surrounding it.

are you sure this is your actual code? I suspect it's rather else action(2) without the curly brackets. In that case commenting action2 out would indeed result in action3 to be interpreted to be within the else-branch.

I have added the code after having commented action_2(). Thanks for reopening the question.

It think it should be fairly obvious that empty braces after an else are valid. I would also find it unlikely that dotPeek has such an obvious bug. I rather suspect that something's gone wrong in the bit we can't see: the process of correctly compiling your code, then correctly decompiling the correct assembly. What does the IL of your compiled code look like? What happens when you debug your compiled code?

Why do the decompilation result of dotPeek have two styles (different bracket and indentation styles)? This doesn't make sense.

Note that dotPeek will use a .pdb file if one exists to get the actual source code. Make sure you delete the .pdb first if you want to see the actual decompilation

I tried to reproduce and failed. I compiled this code, deleted the pdb, loaded the DLL into dotPeek 2021.3.2, and got this

@canton7: Thanks for your effort to reproduce it. It looks like a glitch, then.

@shingo: there was no different style. My question is a summary of the actual problem.

@Dominique There is a different style: the if has braces, but the else does not. By default, dotPeek does not add braces. Can you actually reproduce the problem with the code you posted, or is the code you posted a "summary" of your actual problem? Note that your question must contain a "minimal complete reproducible example". If what you post doesn't reproduce the problem, you're wasting everyone's time

@canton7: I've seen a behaviour which looked wrong and I've mentioned it here as a question. Thanks to you effort we now know it's just a glitch and it is not reproducible. I'm closing this question, no more effort needs to be spent to it.

Did you observe the incorrect behaviour with exactly the code you posted in your question (i.e. did you run the code in your question in isolation and reproduce the problem), or did you only see the incorrect behaviour with some other code, and then approximated that code with the code in your question, but didn't actually see that problem with the code in your question specifically?

@canton7: both action_1 and action_2 were in fact a bunch of actions. I just made a summary in order to be able to ask a clear question (which I always do in order not to publicly demonstrate the source code of my employer). Normally this is working fine, but glitches are always possible.

@Dominique Did you run the exact code in your question, and did it reproduce your problem? Yes or no

@canton7: No, I didn't.

Right, so your question does not contain a [mcve]. And in fact it contains outright falsehoods (you said "I have put action_2() in comment, compiled it and (using JetBrains) decompiled" etc when that simply wasn't true). Simplifying the problem is great, but please make sure that your simplification still reproduces the problem. It's most likely that as part of your "simplification", you cut out the very thing which was causing the problem. That, naturally, makes our lives impossible.

To answer your question with reference to the spec: an if statement precedes an embedded_statement. This can be many things, one of which is a block. A block is '{' statement_list? '}', where statement_list is optional. Therefore, { } is a valid block.
Therefore, the construct else { } is valid, where the { } is the embedded_statement associated with the else.
The docs for if statements say:


If the Boolean expression yields false and if an else part is present, control is transferred to the second embedded statement. When and if control reaches the end point of that statement, control is transferred to the end point of the if statement.


Therefore, anything after the second embedded statement is not conditional on the if condition.
